# Copy values between objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, reflection

I am writing a utility to copy specific data from a backend SQL database to a client computers SQL  Express database. The backend database and the client database are identical. The data are for surveyors that go to remote sites without network.
I am using a REST service and using Entity Framework both on the Service and on the proxy. I am copying the property values with this code:

```
private void GatherFrom<TSelf, TSource>(TSelf self, TSource source)
{
    PropertyInfo[] sourceAllProperties = source.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo sourceProperty in sourceAllProperties)
    {
        PropertyInfo selfProperty = self.GetType().GetProperty(sourceProperty.Name);
        if (selfProperty.CanRead
            && (selfProperty.GetSetMethod(true) != null && !selfProperty.GetSetMethod(true).IsPrivate)
            && (selfProperty.GetSetMethod().Attributes & MethodAttributes.Static) == 0
            && selfProperty.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(sourceProperty.PropertyType))
        {
            var sourceValue = sourceProperty.GetValue(source);
            selfProperty.SetValue(self, sourceValue);
        }
    }
}
```

This works all fine.

But when I apply the new data:

```
Surveys newSurvey = new Surveys();

GatherFrom(newSurvey, survey);

localSurveys.Add(newSurvey);
```

I get into problems because I have ambiguous types from remote and local in the same namespace.

Any idea how to split it up?

Comment: Use full namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the full namespaces of the objects that are ambiguous. For example:

```
LocalNamespace.Something.Surveys localSurveys;
RemoteNamespace.Something.Surveys remoteSurveys;
```

You can also import the namespaces with an alias:

```
using Local = LocalNamespace.Something;
using Remote = RemoteNamespace.Something;

Local.Surveys localSurveys;
Remote.Surveys remoteSurveys;
```

Comment: In Entity Framework a Survey has a reference to other classes. And when I try to add a survey, the survey values are applied OK, but the referenced Data Classes have the same name, and Entity Framework stop with this error:
<br/>
The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type 'ReferencedClass'. Previously found CLR type 'Namespace.DataClient.ReferencedClass', newly found CLR type 'Namespace.DataClient.SurveyServiceReference.ReferencedClass'.

Comment: Mode the different EDM types into completely different namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

It was not just that easy!
First I changed the Code Generation Strategy from T4 to Legacy ObjectContent. This can be done in the Entity Framework Model Diagram. I did that in both ends of the service setup. Remeber to delete the two .tt files nested under the .edmx. Then I set the Custom Tool Namespace for the .edmx (with the model window closed) to a different namespace.

That worked it for me :-)